# Django authentication not working in production, but works locally. Model doesn't use OnetoOnefield

Tags: python, django, azure, heroku

Super user creation works fine and i can access them in the admin pannel. When users however create an account they are added as users but are not propagated into the FacebookProfile model (therefore i cant add their id, webpull etc..) (they propagate fine in development with sqllite3)

I'm using mysql on azure.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django import forms


class FacebookProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

     id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key = True)
     webpull= models.CharField(max_length =1000, null = True)
     score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, editable = True)
     times_called = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, editable = True)
     level = models.FloatField(default = 0, editable =True)
```

my forms for facebook user
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import FacebookProfile


#facebook api linkage
class FacebookUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)


class FacebookProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FacebookProfile
        fields = ('id', 'year_formed', 'webpull',)
```

my custom authentication system
auth_backend.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, username = None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username = username)
        except:
            return None
```

my views from where I'm processing the entered parameters from Facebook API and storing them in the models
views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        print ('ive been posted')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        print (first_name, last_name, username)

        facebook_user = FacebookUserForm(data=request.POST)
        facebook_profile = FacebookProfileForm()

        has_account = authenticate(username = username)
        print (has_account)

        if has_account:
            print ('this has account')
            login(request, has_account)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:

            id_ = request.POST.get('username')
            webpull = request.POST.get('webpull')


            print (id_, birthday, webpull)

            print (facebook_user)

            user = facebook_user.save()
            profile = facebook_profile.save(commit = False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.webpull = webpull
            profile.id = id_


            profile.save()



            now_has_account = authenticate(username = username)
            login(request, now_has_account)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

my production settings.py

```
  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

        'authentication.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend',

        ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'),
    )
```

I'ts an authentication method without a password.

Now is the problem with OnetoOneField in the model? i don't see why everything works locally, but when i push to heroku the only thing that doesn't work is the propagation of the user to FacebookProfile.

Comment: `id_ = request.POST.get('username')` looks like `id_` is not integer, as required by PositiveIntegerField field. Can you check will it work if you put there integer?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner im storing the id returned by Facebook as username (bad practice sorry) so username is an integer like 1002131342321